# unusual sql error

Tags: mysql, sql

so i've been stuck on this sql error for some time.

this is the SQL line i'm using:

```
INSERT INTO images (image_name, orientation, restored, commercial, automotive, bespoke, before, after, date_added) 
VALUES ('image4-after.jpg', 'portrait', '1', '1', '1', '1', '24', '5', '2012-07-08')
```

using this structure:

```
image_id - int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
image_name - varchar(40)
orientation - varchar(4)
restored - tinyint(1)
commercial - tinyint(1)
automotive - tinyint(1)
bespoke - tinyint(1)
before - int(11)
after - int(11)
date_added - date
```

getting the error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'before, after, date_added) VALUES ('image4-after.jpg',
>   'portrait', '1', '1', '1'' at line 1

can anybody please tell me what i've done wrong?

thanks

Comment: ^ None of those things matter with syntax errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BEFORE`  is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to quote it with backticks to use it as a table or column identifier.

```
INSERT INTO images (image_name, orientation, restored, commercial, automotive, bespoke, `before`, after, date_added) 
VALUES ('image4-after.jpg', 'portrait', '1', '1', '1', '1', '24', '5', '2012-07-08')
```

`AFTER` is not reserved, however.

Whenever a 1064 error points to something non-obvious syntactically in its `right syntax to use near...` indicator, look to the reserved words list.

Comment: well that explains a lot! thanks for that insane response time :)

Answer (score 3):

`BEFORE` is a keyword, according to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Try escaping the field name with backticks (`).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is because before is a reserved word in mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Try surrounding before with backwards quotes:  `before`.